# Delete log files on Virtual Host

Tags: linux, debian, virtualhost, log-files

I have a few virtualhosts set up on my machine, and the server keeps crashing because of the disk space being too full. I've checked out and it seems that one of my virtual host log folder is 2Gb. In it there are hundreds of log files, either gzipped or not.

My question is, is there an easy way to delete all that without deleting the current logs being used? Also, while at it, is there a way to tell the server to keep say 5 logs files at all time and delete the others?

Server is Debian.

thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you just use logrotate?

Comment: Debain ships with [`logrotate`](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/logrotate).

Comment: Coz I didn't know it was available, and not sure how to use it. Now how can I delete all these files that are already there?

Comment: And I see that logrotate would restart the server every night? Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look for logrotate , you have many tutorial available on Internet, a quick search on Google and I found this [tutorial](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-debian-part-1).

Logrotate run every day with cron.daily, the script read /etc/logrotate.conf , this file contain all default configuration. Logrotate read other file in the directory /etc/logrotate.d.

So you can perform log rotation every day and keep only 5 day, to set this configuration you must define , in the file /etc/logrotate.conf:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
daily
# keep 5 days worth of backlogs
rotate 5
```

You can add the option **compress** to compress rotated files.
Take a look in files under /etc/logrotate.d to be sure your configuration is not overwrite.

you can do many things with logrotate take few time to read the documentation.